# Изменяется поток выполнения при отсутвии аргументов (Click)

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, python-click

В качестве парсера командной строки использовался Click. Поведение при вызове функции hello и hello --version одинаковое (вызывается функция version). Как это исправить?

```
def print_version(ctx, param, value):
    click.echo('Version 1.0')
    ctx.exit()

@main.command()
@click.option('--version', is_flag=True, callback=print_version,
          expose_value=False, is_eager=True)
def hello():
     click.echo('Hello World!')
```

Желаемый вывод:

> ```
> $ hello
> Hello World!
> $ hello --version
> Version 1.0
> ```

Фактический вывод:

> ```
> $ hello
> Version 1.0
> $ hello --version
> Version 1.0
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_version(ctx, param, value):
    if not value or ctx.resilient_parsing:
        return
    click.echo('Version 1.0')
    ctx.exit()
```